# addtocontentsline only if not empty

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm using a macro, which does this:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\string\iffoo bla \string\fi}
```

When compiled normally, `foo` is `false`, so the line should not appear in the toc. But when the `.toc` file is included in some other script, I set `foo` to `true` in that script and the same `.toc` file should also show the `bla`.

If I use the code as above, I'll get

```
\contentsline {section}{\iffoo bla \fi }{1}{section.0.1}
```

which does print an `.....` line without any text when `foo` is false. What I probably do need is this:

```
\iffoo \contentsline {section}{bla}{1}{section.0.1} \fi
```

How do I get this?

Comment: `\addtocontents` or `\addcontentsline`... but not `\addtocontentsline` (at least I don't know that macro). Please provide an MWE to make this question clearer

Comment: `\string\iffoo\ bla\string\fi` would be better. In addition, I think, that `\iffoo \addcontentsline{....} \fi is actually the correct thing you want to have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the content line should be there only `\iffoo` expands to true, it's no use to do the test inside of the 3rd argument of `\addcontentsline`, since this will start the `\contentsline` machine in the `.aux` file, leading to an `.toc` entry anyway.

To prevent this, the test must be **outside** of `\addcontentsline`. See the two different behaviours in the example below. The two 'empty' lines are the result of the testing within `\addcontentsline` -- this is not wanted, I am pretty sure.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\newif\iffoo

\foofalse
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\section{First}
\blindtext

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\string\iffoo\ Will be in the toc or empty \string\fi}

\iffoo
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Will be in the toc only if foo is true}

\fi


\section{another one}
\footrue

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\string\iffoo\ Will not appear  in the toc but the page number will be there  \string\fi}

\iffoo
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Will be in the toc only if foo is true too}
\fi



\end{document}
```

[image]